# How to use x IN y, where y is a list or query for integer

Tags: postgresql, python-3.6, peewee

how do I make the selection with .in_ if it is integer? When I try to insert an integer, I get an error
My column is array and integer.

```
#My try
check = await db.execute(MarriagePlayer.select()
    .where(
    (MarriagePlayer.male_childrens.in_([1,2])) |
    (MarriagePlayer.woman_childrens.in_([1]),
     MarriagePlayer.chat_id == msg.receiver_id)))

#Error
site-packages\playhouse\postgres_ext.py", line 192, in db_value
return value if isinstance(value, list) else list(value)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into operator precedence issues. Try breaking up the pieces and you'll see what happened:

```
part1 = MarriagePlayer.male_childrens.in_([1,2])
part2 = MarriagePlayer.woman_childrens.in_([1])
part3 = MarriagePlayer.chat_id == msg.receiver_id

check = await db.execute(MarriagePlayer.select().where(part1 | (part2 & part3)))
```

**Edit**: I just reread and realized your `x_childrens` columns are **arrays**. You'll probably want to use the `.contains()` / `.contains_any()` methods instead of `.in_()`.

Comment: i tryt to execute this code but i get the same problem
`part1 = MarriagePlayer.male_childrens.in_([1, 2])
 check = await db.execute(MarriagePlayer.select().where(part1))`

Comment: I just updated. Didn't realize you were working with an array.